# Trying to understand the conversion process from Class diagram to Object diagram

Tags: java, class, object, uml, diagram

I'm trying to understand how to go from Class Diagram to Object Diagram. I've read several tutorials, watched some videos online and I can't get my head around it. A lot of the examples I'm finding are where the class and object diagram attributes and scenario are different. The ones I'm finding that are the same are too basic.

I understand an object diagram shows instances of the classes and attributes, but I'm not understand how to correctly convert from class to object with the attached diagram.

[image: class diagram]

Comment: Wealthy Scout would inherit Scout. Scout is associated with Camping trip and badge award. Camping trip is associated with Camp Site and Badge Awarded is associated with Badge Specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects are instances, as you describe. As such, you'd need to think about how your class model would be instanced at runtime. It's likely that the instances you have at runtime will vary based on the actual scenarios your software encounters, which is why different object diagrams can vary structurally even if they are all tied back to the same classes.

- If you have multiple instances of a class, each instance would be represented using a separate object in UML.
- Anything that is abstract in class terms cannot be (by definition) instanced, so you will only have instances of concrete sub-types (e.g. if Scout was abstract).
- Even if a class has multiple attributes, only some of those attributes may receive values at runtime, so you may only define a *runtime state* for your object that is a sub-set of the attributes on a class.

This is an example based on your class model, but depending on the scenario there could be many such incarnations:

[image]

Comment: You wrote: "only some of those attributes may receive values at runtime". I think attributes have multiplicity `1` by default. If you need instances that do not have a value for a particular attribute, then the attribute should have multiplicity `[0..1]`.

Answer (score 0):

So in your class diagram, you have names of what is needed to be apart of the class. In your object diagram, you will expand upon your class diagram but list the type/object of the fields you need.

In your provided example, let's look at camp site, you have two fields, name and location. Well now in your object diagram, how will you represent these fields, what data type of object will you use. They will most likely be stored as a String for each, or maybe you have a list of floats to represent longitude and latitude. It's essentially how you are planning on implementing the class so people who see the diagrams can replicate and understand your design practices.

This was a simple explanation and we could further explain how everything would be converted but it follows the same general format.

Comment: I don't think so. An object diagram is not used to elaborate on the data types of the fields, but to show an example situation of the instances that could exist. If you want to elaborate on the data types, then you should do that in the class diagram.